# Want Bxslider Pager slide direct to appropriate slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using bxSlider, suppose I have 5 content of slide, I want when I'm on the 1st slide, click on the 5th pager, its slide next to 5th. like (1st slide next to 5th), not like 1st slide(2nd 3rd 4th) then 5th, please help me out.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  controls: false,
autoHover: true,
 pagerCustom: '#bx-pager'
});
```

Comment: Post the working  code you have tried.

Comment: i post the code

Comment: this can be achieved but then there will be no animation

Comment: no animation means,, it will jump or slide.. i just want a normal slide, like a single slide,  1 to 2 equals  1 to 5 or 4 or 3

Comment: please tell me.

Comment: it will just jump.. there will not be any sliding ..

Comment: please also tell if i use any other slider, width this features.

Comment: its ok ,, how to do that.

Comment: ok let me post an answer

Answer (score 1):

> Here you go :

```js
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  speed: 0,
  captions: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1.1/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.1.1/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide-One" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide-Two" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide-Three" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/800x250/5E7074/FFFFFF&text=Slide-Four" />
  </li>
</ul>
```